# Can changing nameservers while keeping the same host impact SEO for websites?

Tags: seo, dns, domain-registration, vps, nameserver

I host several Italian sites in a Virtual Private Server (VPS) located in Italy. At the moment, most of the domains are registered by the same provider, so all the nameservers are located in Italy too.

I want to switch to a new ISP, whose nameservers are located in the UK, USA and Canada, for domain registration, while keeping the same VPS hosting.

Could the DNS change have an impact on those websites' SEO?

Keep in mind that the actual host (the `A` record in DNS) will remain the same.

Comment: Are your websites targeting an Italian audience? What TLD's are your domains?

Comment: All of them are targeting Italian users, some have a multilingual version, but mainly i'm hosting small/medium local business websites. TLD's are mostly .com and .it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically addressing whether changing your nameservers alone would affect your SEO, the answer is no (unless there was a problem with their service).

[Nameservers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) translate domain names and hostnames into corresponding IP addresses used to locate servers, which is then propagated and cached throughout the Internet. When a domain or hostname lookup is done by a client application or search engine bot, they'll be directed to the same IP address for your websites's server as before.

Search engines like Google can use your server's IP address as signal for international domains (e.g, `.com`, `.org`, `.eu`, etc...), along with content and links for your site, to help [geotarget](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) it. However, since the IP address for your website's server won't be changing, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you dan. Should i lookup for my future nameservers on [CBL](http://cbl.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi) and other blacklists, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: No problem. If they're a reputable DNS provider, then that's not really necessary. If you're going to be hosting your site or mail server with them, then you can lookup their IP's in [DNSBL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) and [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)) databases to see if there's been an issue with them regarding spam or exploits in the past.